# Installing opencv4[contrib] with vcpkg.json

Tags: opencv, cmake, vcpkg

On vcpkg.json I have

```
{
  "dependencies": [ "fmt", "opencv4"]
}
```

And when I open the corresponding cmake project on qtcreator, looking at the General Messages tab I see

```
[cmake] Running /Users/user/Qt/Tools/CMake/CMake.app/Contents/bin/cmake -S /Users/user/2024/Projecs/opencv2 -B /Users/user/2024/Projecs/opencv2/build in /Users/user/2024/Projecs/opencv2/build.
[cmake] -- Running vcpkg install
[cmake] Detecting compiler hash for triplet arm64-osx...
[cmake] The following packages will be built and installed:
[cmake]   * flatbuffers:arm64-osx@23.5.26#1
[cmake]     fmt:arm64-osx@10.1.1
[cmake]   * libjpeg-turbo:arm64-osx@3.0.1
[cmake]   * liblzma:arm64-osx@5.4.4
[cmake]   * libpng:arm64-osx@1.6.40
[cmake]   * libwebp[core,libwebpmux,nearlossless,simd]:arm64-osx@1.3.2
[cmake]     opencv4[core,default-features,dnn,jpeg,png,quirc,tiff,webp]:arm64-osx@4.8.0#12
[cmake]   * protobuf:arm64-osx@3.21.12
[cmake]   * quirc:arm64-osx@1.1#3
[cmake]   * tiff[core,jpeg,lzma,zip]:arm64-osx@4.6.0#1
[cmake]   * vcpkg-cmake:arm64-osx@2023-05-04
[cmake]   * vcpkg-cmake-config:arm64-osx@2022-02-06#1
[cmake]   * vcpkg-get-python-packages:arm64-osx@2023-07-28
[cmake]   * zlib:arm64-osx@1.3
[cmake] Additional packages (*) will be modified to complete this operation.
```

So it seems a few opencv modules will be installed

```
opencv4[core,default-features,dnn,jpeg,png,quirc,tiff,webp]
```

However it seems that's not all, from `./vcpkg search opencv4` I see

```
opencv4                  4.8.0#12         computer vision library
opencv4[ade]                              graph api
opencv4[contrib]                          opencv_contrib module
opencv4[cuda]                             CUDA support for opencv
opencv4[cudnn]                            cuDNN support for opencv
opencv4[dc1394]                           Dc1394 support for opencv
opencv4[default-features]                 Platform-dependent default features
opencv4[dnn]                              Enable dnn module
opencv4[dnn-cuda]                         Build dnn module with CUDA support
opencv4[eigen]                            Eigen support for opencv
opencv4[ffmpeg]                           ffmpeg support for opencv
opencv4[freetype]                         Freetype support for opencv
opencv4[gdcm]                             GDCM support for opencv
opencv4[gstreamer]                        gstreamer support for opencv
opencv4[gtk]                              GTK support for opencv
opencv4[halide]                           Halide support for opencv
opencv4[ipp]                              Enable Intel Integrated Performance Primitives
opencv4[jasper]                           JPEG 2000 support for opencv (deprecated)
opencv4[jpeg]                             JPEG support for opencv
opencv4[lapack]                           LAPACK support for opencv
opencv4[nonfree]                          allow nonfree and unredistributable libraries
opencv4[openexr]                          OpenEXR support for opencv
opencv4[opengl]                           opengl support for opencv
opencv4[openjpeg]                         JPEG 2000 support for opencv
opencv4[openmp]                           Enable openmp support for opencv
opencv4[openvino]                         OpenVINO support for OpenCV DNN
opencv4[ovis]                             opencv_ovis module
opencv4[png]                              PNG support for opencv
opencv4[python]                           Python wrapper support for opencv
opencv4[qt]                               Qt GUI support for opencv
opencv4[quirc]                            Enable QR code module
opencv4[sfm]                              opencv_sfm module
opencv4[tbb]                              Enable Intel Threading Building Blocks
opencv4[tiff]                             TIFF support for opencv
opencv4[vtk]                              vtk support for opencv
opencv4[webp]                             WebP support for opencv
opencv4[world]                            Compile to a single package support for opencv
```

What happens if I need one of those modules that is not installed? It seems vcpkg.json does not accept `opencv4[contrib]`. So only option is to install it manually with `./vcpkg install opencv4[contrib]`?